# My models will not load into my Aframe scene. Any ideas?

Tags: aframe

https://repl.it/@ThomasWirta/aframeproject2

This is the link to my project. I don't know why my models will not load into my scene, and the console is showing no errors. Any and all help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Please post some code or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)